# Binary Tree (insert and search within radius)

Tags: c++, search, insert, binary-search-tree

I am writing a binary tree search program but I'm not sure how to add nodes and search through them. The nodes come from a .txt file that is being read with a different file so just assume that already works.

The text file looks like:
Name     Location
Old Building 31.2222
New Building 21.2111

Like I said, the program already reads in the file so that's not an issue. However, I have to insert the name and location into the nodes of the binary tree. Then I have to search everything within a range which is where the plus minus comes from.

Side note: my copy constructor may be incorrect as well though it complies properly.

Thanks for the help!

```
#ifndef BINTREE_HPP
#define BINTREE_HPP

#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class bintree {

// A binary search tree for locations in Lineland.

// Notes: 
// - Assume a flat, one-dimensional world with locations from -180 to 180.
// - All locations and distances are measured in the same units (degrees).

public:
// Default constructor
bintree() {
   this->root = NULL;
}

// Copy constructor
bintree(const bintree &t) {
  this -> root = NULL;
*this = t;
 }

// Destructor
~bintree() {

}


 // Copy assignment is implemented using the copy-swap idiom

 friend void swap(bintree &t1, bintree &t2) {
 using std::swap;
 // Swap all data members here, e.g.,
 // swap(t1.foo, t2.foo);
 // Pointers should be swapped -- but not the things they point to.
 }
 bintree &operator= (bintree other) {
 // You don't need to modify this function.
 swap(*this, other);
 return *this;
 }

 void insert(const std::string& name, double p) {
   // insert node with name and location (p)
 }

 void within_radius(double p, double r, std::vector<std::string> &result) const {
  // Search for elements within the range `p` plus or minus `r`.
  // Clears `result` and puts the elements in `result`.
  // Postcondition: `result` contains all (and only) elements of the
  // tree, in any order, that lie within the range `p` plus or minus
  // `r`.
  }

private:

struct node
{
 node *left;
 node *right;

};

node* root; 

};

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your nodes need to hold the data:

```
struct node
{
 node *left;
 node *right;
 std::string name;  // This is the key for your reasearch
 double p;          // followed by other data 
};
```

Then you can think to browsing through your tree to insert a new node.
In this example, I assume that you can insert several nodes with the same name.

```
void insert(const std::string& name, double p) {
   node *n = new node;       // create a new node
   n->name=name; n->p=p;     // intialise the data payload
   n->left=n->right=nullptr; // and make it a leaf.

   if (root==nullptr)        // if tree is empty, 
      root = n;                   // add the new node. 

   else {                    // else find where to insert it
      node* t=root; 
      while (true) {
          if (t->name > n->name) {     // go to left
              if (t->left==nullptr) {
                 t->left = n;     
                 break;  
              }
              else t=t->left; 
          }
          else if (t->name == n->name) { // insert between current and next
              n->right = t->right; 
              t->right = n; 
              break; 
          }
          else {                         // go to right 
              if (t->right==nullptr) {
                 t->right = n;     
                 break;  
              }
              else t=t->right; 
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Here a [live demo](http://ideone.com/cqXI1j).

Note that I have only answered your insertion question,  you still have to do a lot on your own (operator= and copy constructor need review, a destructor needs to be created, etc...)